# Which item have the affix +X% damage against <mob type> / Elites?

Tags: diablo-iii

Basically, I'm searching for items that gives a bonus damage against certain mobs. I already know a few, but I would like to have a complete list of them (with the possible bonus range on their lvl70 version).

[(If you wonder why I'm looking for those items, you may want to read this other question I asked on Arqade)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163656/does-bonus-damage-against-mob-type-apply-to-elite-mobs-of-the-same-type)

Don't hesitate to help me if you know one or more :)

Bonus to {mob type}:

- Pig Sticker: +15-30% damage to Beasts / +15-30% damage to Humans
- Tyrael's Might: +10-20% damage to Demons

Bonus to Elites:

- Unity: +12-15% damage to Elites
- Stone of Jordan: +25-30% damage to Elites

Comment: Aughild's set bonus (3) => +15% to elite and the quiver BackBone Arrow (4-7) and Archfiend Arrow (5-8), thats the only i know from the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list does not take in account every legacy items such as The star of Azkaranth which could in the pre 2.0 patch roll (3-5% vs elites) but no longer does ([Legacy one](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-star-of-azkaranth-3rGE4L) vs [RoS one](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-star-of-azkaranth))

### Bonus vs Elite

- [Black Bone Arrows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/black-bone-arrows) (quiver : 5-8%)
- [Archfiend Arrows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/archfiend-arrows) (quiver : 4-7%)
- [Hellcat Waistguard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hellcat-waistguard) (belt : 3-5%)
- [Halcyons Ascent](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/halcyons-ascent) (amulet : 10-15%)
- [Stone of Jordan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) (ring : 25-30%)
- [Unity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/unity) (ring : 12-15%)
- [Blood Magic Blade](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/bloodmagic-blade) (1 hand blade : 4-7%)
- [Sun Keeper](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mace-1h/#filter=elite) (1 hand mace : 15-30%)
- [Empyrean Messenger](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/empyrean-messenger) (1 hand spear : 5-8%)
- [Venomhusk](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/venomhusk) (bow : 8-9%)
- [Sydryu Crust](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sydryu-crust) (bow 9-10%)
- [Ruinstoke](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/ruinstoke) (wand : 4-7%)
- [Aughild's Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/aughilds-spike) (bonus 3 : 15%)
- [Blackthorne's Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blackthornes-duncraig-cross) (bonus 2 : 10%)
- Socketin a weapon with a [diamond](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem/) (2-20% depending on the diamond quality)

### Bonus vs other types

- [Tyrael's Might](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tyraels-might) (chest : 10-20% damage to Demons)
- [Pig Sticker](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/pig-sticker) (1 hand dagger : 15-30% damage to Beasts and 15-30% damage to Humans)
- [Monster Hunter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/monster-hunter) (1 hand sword : 5-6% damage to Beasts)
- [Sever](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sever) (1 hand sword : 5-10% damage to Demons)

Comment: Is this an exhaustive list, or only what you know of? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Divinicus As  far as I know its exhaustive, I went through the item list on the bnet online item guide and used the filter "elite" (to find damage vs elite) and "damage to" (like in damage to Demons/Beasts). I might have missed a bonus set but for the primary affixes of orange legendaries that's it. IF someone point out some missing one, Ill edit the post.

Comment: just to be complete, you should include diamonds in weapons.